# WSL python3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named xxx

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using python 3.6.2 on WSL (Windows Linux subsystem) and trying to set tensorflow environment (and installing some other libraries as well). However, i always get an error when I exit and login again:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'`

So I have to reinstall the libraries again and the problem will be fixed until I logout again. This problem only happens with my python3. I also tried `python3` and use `import tensorflow` to find the library, but it also returned the same error. 
I think the problem may be related with system path because python cannot find the library in its original searching directory. when i enter `sys.path` it returns:

`['', '/home/jeoker/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip', '/home/jeoker/anaconda3/lib/python3.6', '/home/jeoker/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/jeoker/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages']`

But when I do `conda list`, the result always show the files in `/home/jeoker/anaconda2`. I tried `sudo pip3 install tensorflow`, but it gived me this: `Requiement already satisfied`. It seems that the path where the libraries are installed is not the same as where python is looking into.
Does anyone know how can I fix this problem? thanks in advance!!

Comment: I am having a similar problem. I installed Seaborn with conda, and I can see  its folder in miniconda directory. But when I run a script that uses Seaborn, it goes `ModuleNotFoundError`. It is not a typo, since it happens only in WSL: when I run on Power Shell, my Python IDE or a real Linux computer, it works. Wish this question was not closed because it is "not reproducible or caused by typos". I involuntary reproduced it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since no one is answering this question, I have to close the question. What I did to overcome the issue was just to uninstall the whole WSL and reinstall it.